# How to copy pandas DataFrame values down to fill 0's?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So basically, how do I convert DataFrame A to DataFrame B?

A:

```
Index Value
01 42
02 0
03 0
04 57
05 0
... ...
```

B:

```
Index Value
01 42
02 42
03 42
04 57
05 57
... ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to convert to floats (if necessary, it won't work for ints) for this to work see the docs on [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and in particular the method used here is `ffill` which means forward fill:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[42,0,0,57,0]})
df
Out[16]:

   value
0     42
1      0
2      0
3     57
4      0

In [17]:
df.value = df.value.astype(float)
df.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
Out[17]:

   value
0     42
1     42
2     42
3     57
4     57
```

You can always convert back after:

```
df.value = df.value.astype(int)
```