# Pandas: Backfilling a DataFrameGroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` object that looks like this:

```
Out[9]:         pts   res  sensor
        0         0     Y   accel
        1         0   NaN   accel
        2         0     N    beta
        3         0   NaN    beta
        4         5   NaN    beta
        5         8   NaN   accel
```

I would like to write some code that first uses the `.groupby()` function to group by `sensor`. And then backfills the `pts` column of each group and forward fills the `res` column of each group. My code attempt looks like this:

```
df_g = df.groupby('sensor')
next_pts = pd.Series(df_g.pts.bfill())
next_res = pd.Series(df_g.res.ffill())

df['next_pts'] = next_pts
df['next_res'] = next_res
df
```

The output was this:

```
Out[11]:         pts  res  sensor next_pts next_res
        0         0     Y   accel       0         Y
        1         0   NaN   accel       0         Y
        2         0     N    beta       0         N
        3         0   NaN    beta       0         N
        4         5   NaN    beta       5         N
        5         8   NaN   accel       8         Y
```

So it seems like the `ffill()` on the `res` column worked, but the `bfill()` on the `pts` column didn't. How do I make it look like this?:

```
Out[12]:         pts  res  sensor next_pts next_res
        0         0     Y   accel       8         Y
        1         0   NaN   accel       8         Y
        2         0     N    beta       5         N
        3         0   NaN    beta       5         N
        4         5   NaN    beta       5         N
        5         8   NaN   accel       8         Y
```

I found this Stack Overflow link that asks a similar question but on a `DataFrame` object, not a `DataFrameGroupBy` object: [How to copy pandas DataFrame values down to fill 0's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343251/how-to-copy-pandas-dataframe-values-down-to-fill-0s)

But when I tried to do something like this on my `DataFrameGroupBy` object, it threw an error: `Cannot access callable attribute 'astype' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Any help would be so much appreciated!!

Comment: `ffill` and `bfill` replace `NaN` values not 0 values, this is by design, you'd have to replace your `0` values with `NaN` values in order to achieve your desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it has a lot to do with `groupby`, but rather with the `?fill` functions, which don't fill int series with 0s.

Perhaps there's a more elegant way to do it, but this worked:

```
>> df.pts = np.where(df.pts == 0, np.NaN, df.pts)
>> df.pts.groupby(df.sensor).apply(lambda g: g.bfill())
0    8
1    8
2    5
3    5
4    5
5    8
dtype: float64
```

Note that you can convert the float series back to ints easily using `.astype`.

**Edit** The first line can be written as

```
>> df.pts.replace(0, np.NaN)
```